# How to set gettext text domain in Poedit?

Tags: gettext, poedit

I need to parse my php files where is used several text-domains. I want to parse just one specific domain (others have been already translated) How to make Poedit to do that?

Is it required to compile mo file bounded to some text-domain? If it is, how to do it in Poedit.

I am using windows and do not want to install Cigwin with Gettext.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need install Cygwin for gettext, because there is ready to use gettext for windows: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gettext.htm

To gather strings for translations you need to create POT/PO files, not binary MO files.
Usually this is done via xgettext utility from gettext.