# How to get (translatable) strings from specific domain with POEdit

Tags: dns, gettext, poedit

I have been trying for hours finding a way to setup [POEdit](http://www.poedit.net) so that it can grab the text from specific domain only

My gettext function looks like this:

```
function ri($id, $parameters = array(), $domain = 'default', $locale = null)
```

A sample call:

```
echo ri('Text %xyz%', array('%xyz%'=>100), 'myDomain');
```

I will need to grab only the text with the domain myDomain to translate, or at least I want POEdit to put these texts into domain specific files. Is there a way to do it?

I found several questions that are similar but the answers don't really tell me what to do (I think I'm such a noob it must be explained in plain English for me to understand):

[How to set gettext text domain in Poedit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240033/how-to-set-gettext-text-domain-in-poedit)

[How to get list of translatable messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896561/how-to-get-list-of-translatable-messages)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I finally figured it out after days of searching, I finally found the answer here:

http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=27691818

> - xgettext recognizes context in strings, and gives a msgctxt field in    the *.pot file, which is recognized by translation software as a
>     context and    is shown as such (check image of Pootle showing context
>     below)
>
>   - This can be done in 3 ways:
>
>     1. String in code should be in the format _t('context','string'); and    xgettext invocation should be in the form --keyword=_t:1c,2
>          (this basically    explains to xgettext that there are 2 arguments in
>          the keyword function, 1st    one is context, 2nd one is string)
>     2. String in code in the format _t('string','context'); and xgettext    invocation should be in the form --keyword=_t:1,2c
>     3. String in the code should be as _t('context|string') and xgettext    invocation should be in the form --keyword=_t:1g

So to answer my own question, I added this to the "sources keywords" tab of Poedit:

```
ri:1,3c
```

ri is the function name, 1 is the location of the stringid, 3 is the location of the context/domain

Hope this helps someone else, I hate all these cryptic documents

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, but where do you specify the textdomain? in your case `myDomain`.

Comment: Ahh I got it, now all strings will be extracted with it's text domain per string is included, so we can't generate the .po based on only certain text domain?

Comment: Yep, I'm looking for answer for way too long and I dont see where have you wrote domain name in fact?

Comment: Is it still that case that we can't extract translatable text for a specific text domain only?

Comment: But domain and context are two different things.

Comment: No idea why this is the accepted answer. Does not solve the question.

Comment: yeah, it confused me too and I got bitchslapped by  grumpy Vaclav. As I read Vaclav other answer it is not possible to mix things in one file. However, it does happen. I use Roots Wp Theme which has it's  own .po file and I have my own translation file. I don't want to remove all the roots entries so I just want to ignore them. I thought I could do that with the context but I was mistaken. This answer kinda confused me in what was possible or not. Ill do some more reading and see if I can come up with a solution for the original question

Answer (score 0):

(This is a repost of my answer to the same thing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30425802/237188).)

Neither GNU gettext tools nor Poedit (which uses them) support this particular misuse of gettext.

In gettext, *domain* is roughly “a piece of software” — a program, a library, a plugin, a theme. As such, it typically resides in a single directory tree and is *alone* there — or at the very least, if you have multiple pieces=domains, you have them organized sanely into some subdirectories that you can limit the extraction to.

Mixing and matching domains within a *single file* as you do is not how gettext was intended to be used, and there’s no reasonable solution to handle it other than using your own helper function, e.g. by wrapping all myDomain texts into `__mydomain` (which you must define, obviously) and adding that to the list of keywords in Poedit when extracting for myDomain and *not* adding that to the list of keywords for other domains' files.