# POedit/xgettext: create context-specific .po file / string import

Tags: poedit, xgettext

POedit/xgettext: create context-specific .po file / string import

Using POedit I'd like to work with 2 separate language files, so translators need only edit one client-specific language file, while the system-specific language file stays intact.

This is my xgettext call:

```
 xgettext --force-po -o %o %C %F -k --keyword=_e:1,2c
```

However, this [How to get (translatable) strings from specific domain with POEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12743214/how-to-get-translatable-strings-from-specific-domain-with-poedit) gets ALL translatable strings.

Now, I want to create a .po file containing ONLY the strings that match a certain context. This is my PHP:

```
# CLIENT-specific: should BE imported into .po file
__('Photo challenge', 'imlang_ext');

# SYSTEM-specific: should NOT be imported into .po file
__('An error has occured.', 'imlang_msg');
```

How can I import only those values that match the imlang_ext context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easy way to do that with neither Poedit nor GNU gettext.

If I may, the problem probably is in *why* you want to do that in the first place. That's not what contexts are for: their purpose is disambiguating otherwise identical strings in the catalog.

Sounds like you're misusing contexts and what you really want is to use two different *domains* (i.e. separate PO files). Which not-so-coincidentally is what the `_e()` function's second argument is, a domain and not a context: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e