# WordPress multiple text domain

Tags: wordpress, internationalization, poedit

I am working on a wordpress theme which is based on `buildpress` and it has its own `languages/en_US.po` translation file. I would like to add my own custom translations, seperated from the main translation file. so I've added some `_e('My string', 'my-domain')` and placed `languages/my-domain_en_US.po`  but how can I make Poedit scan only my text domain since i'm scanning the theme and getting all the buildpress's strings. any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get (translatable) strings from specific domain with POEdit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12743214/how-to-get-translatable-strings-from-specific-domain-with-poedit)

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422256/using-poedit-only-search-for-strings-in-specific-domain